# Retrieve just one field from JSON string in Java

Tags: java, json, object

Is there a way to just one field from the JSON string? My code is as follows:

```
Object obj = parser.parse(resp);
System.out.println(obj);
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.add(obj);

JSONObject obj2 = (JSONObject)array.get(0); //Getting NPE here
//Object obj3 = obj2.get("data");

System.out.println("Data: " + obj2.get("data"));
//System.out.println("Email: " + obj3.get("email_address"));
```

I'm using the following libraries

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
```

From the response string resp, I just need data.email_address. I am unable to find a way to do it.

Comment: Your answer is applicable to Javascript not Java. I am looking at how to do it in Java.

Comment: There are JS libraries for Java, but it's probably not the most elegant way.

Comment: What would be a good library? I am using one. The problem is, all the libraries that I have used make me want to strongly type the object but the response returns about 100 different elements and I only need one so i'm not sure what the best way to do it is.

Comment: I only know Nashorn...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So if this is your input:

```
{
    "data": {
        "email_address": "example@example.com"
    }
}
```

You first will need to make it a `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(json);
```

And then you can get `data`, another `JSONObject`:

```
JSONObject data = (JSONObject) object.get("data")
```

And from your `data` Object you can get `email_address`:

```
String email = data.get("email_address").toString();
```

If your input is an array of users, like this:

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "data": {
        "email_address": "example@example.com"
      }
    },
    {
      "data": {
        "email_address": "exapmle2@example2.com"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

You can get it the same way:

```
JSONObject object = (JSONObject) new JSONParser().parse(json);
JSONArray users = (JSONArray) object.get("users");
JSONObject user0 = (JSONObject) users.get(0);
JSONObject user0data = (JSONObject) user0.get("data");
String email = user0data.get("email_address").toString();
```

First parse the whole JSON into an Object. Then get an array called `users`, from that array, get index 0. From that Object, get `data`, and then `email_address`

Comment: My reply was too long so I updated the main post with the details. Thanks for the great answer, I believe i'm close.

Comment: Thank you for a very thorough answer with different scenarios!

Comment: is there a '.' (dot) notation? like object.get("data.email_address")?

Answer (score 1):

The other option is to use [jsonpath](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath).

Using the same Json blob as Lorant:

```
    {
        "data": {
            "email_address": "example@example.com"
        }
    }
```

You would use the following expression.

```
    $.data.email_address
```

Or if it was an array, simply.

```
    $.users.[data].email_address
```

An [online tool](http://jsonpath.com/) can be used to experiment and learn the syntax, but if you know xpath it should be somewhat familiar already.

Answer (score 0):

```
import org.json.JSONObject;


JSONObject json = new JSONObject(record);
json.getString("fieldName"));
```

Comment: That returns the value associated with the given key, not the field like the OP requested.